# Track current Location of Application user in ionic

Tags: google-maps, geolocation, ionic-framework

I wanted to create an Ionic application where manager keeps an eye on his sales executive. Manager should know all his sales person location in his mobile(means in app). When manager selects an user and click on find user App should display his current location on map.

I have completed with getting current location of the user using this

```
angular.module('ionic.example', ['ionic'])

.controller('MapCtrl', function($scope, $ionicLoading, $compile) {
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(43.07493,-89.381388);
  function initialize() {

    var mapOptions = {
      center: myLatlng,
      zoom: 16,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),
        mapOptions);

    //Marker + infowindow + angularjs compiled ng-click
    var contentString = "<div><a ng-click='clickTest()'>Click me!</a></div>";
    var compiled = $compile(contentString)($scope);

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: compiled[0]
    });

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatlng,
      map: map,
      title: 'Uluru (Ayers Rock)'
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
      infowindow.open(map,marker);
    });

    $scope.map = map;
  }
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

  $scope.centerOnMe = function() {
    if(!$scope.map) {
      return;
    }

    $scope.loading = $ionicLoading.show({
      content: 'Getting current location...',
      showBackdrop: false
    });

    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(pos) {
      $scope.map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(pos.coords.latitude, pos.coords.longitude));
      console.log(pos.coords.latitude);
      myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(pos.coords.latitude,pos.coords.longitude);
      initialize();
      console.log(pos.coords.latitude+","+pos.coords.longitude);
      $scope.loading.hide();
    }, function(error) {
      alert('Unable to get location: ' + error.message);
    });
  };

  $scope.clickTest = function() {
    alert('Example of infowindow with ng-click')
  };

});
```

Html Code

```
<html ng-app="ionic.example">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Map</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">

<link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
<script src="js/index.js"></script>

<!-- google maps javascript -->
<script src="//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyB16sGmIekuGIvYOfNoW9T44377IU2d2Es&sensor=true"></script>

</head>
  <body ng-controller="MapCtrl">
    <ion-header-bar class="bar-dark" >
      <h1 class="title">Map</h1>
    </ion-header-bar>
    <ion-content>
      <div id="map" data-tap-disabled="true"></div>
    </ion-content>
    <ion-footer-bar class="bar-dark">
      <a ng-click="centerOnMe()" class="button button-icon icon ion-navigate">Find Me</a>
    </ion-footer-bar>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: what's the problem are you facing?

Comment: You as a programmer should not work for the wrong people. Remember that tracking users' positions can be a violent privacy breach!

Comment: @niklas I agreed at your point, but this app is not for all peoples. It is a monitoring app which helps to monitor sales executive location to their respective manager

Comment: still it does not necessarily make it more ethical https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Panopticism#Panopticism_and_capitalism

Comment: Hi @VaibhavGole did you any solution?

Comment: @DSP I used plugin to run the app in background mode and called the API after 2 min to store the location.

Comment: @VaibhavGole can you tell the plugin name? I am using background geolocation plugin, but it's not showing accurately.